# What does "does not cancel on the interval" mean?

Tags: calculus, terminology

I have a question which asks me to consider the system
$$f(x)=a+bx+\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)},\qquad x\in I,$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials, and stipulates "$Q(x)$ does not cancel on the interval $I$ ".

**What does this mean?**

Does this mean $Q(x)\neq0$ on this interval, or that $Q(x)\neq P(x)$ on this interval, or perhaps something else? I have tried Googling the expression but couldn't find anything, and I haven't came across it before.

Comment: Is the question in English?

Comment: @Gae.S. Yes, it is in English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might mean that whenever $Q(x)=0$, then $P(x)\ne 0$. And the other way around, $P(x)=0\implies Q(x)=0$, but that is probably the less interesting case.

As $P,Q$ are polynomials, the usual use of "cancel" is that a common factor can be removed, here that could be interpreted the way that $P,Q$ do not have a common factor that has roots inside that interval.

But it might also be an unfortunate word choice and the condition to express was that "$Q$ does not vanish on $I$", which indeed then means that there are no roots of $Q$ in $I$.

Comment: Without getting you to answer my homework, the rest of the question is about whether $f(x)$ is continuous, with continuity being desirable for the answer - would this make it more likely that "$Q$ does not vanish on $I$" is the correct interpretation? Absolutely no offence meant, but the question was written by someone who has English as a second language. Otherwise I'm unsure how continuity could be achieved with $Q(x)$ ever being equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, if you want to apply the arithmetic rules for continuous functions, then $Q$ must be zero-free on the interval. If a root of $Q$ can "cancel" against a root of $P$, then the correct claim is a little harder to formulate.

Answer (score -1):

It means $Q(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in I$.